# Palindrome numberr

Tags: python, palindrome

I was making research on writing a code to check for Palindrome number in Python and I came across this

```py
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        rev = 0
        init_n = x
        if (x < 0):
            return False
        while x != 0:
            rev = (rev * 10) + x % 10
            x = x // 10

        if (rev == init_n):
            return True
```

Question:  Please can someone explain the while x!=0: loop for me

Comment: It loops while `x` isn't `0`. Please see [ask] and [tour] about asking good questions.

Comment: Looks like your indentation is all over the place. Please make sure your code is formatted properly, as indentation has a huge impact on Python.

Comment: Seems complicated. Why not simply work it as a string?:  `def isPalindrome(x): return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

While I agree your question could use some extra clarification, or you don't quite understand the code you posted. Here's an explanation. Say we start x = 123
The code:

```
    while x != 0:
        rev = (rev*10) +  x % 10
        x = x // 10
```

rev = reverse and x is our start number and the edited versions we create as we go.

Each iteration does the following

> The first line takes our previous rev and opens up the ones digit before adding the ones digit from the end of x's list. This is done via the mod operator in python which returns the remainder of a number. When applied with the number 10 what is left is the ones digit. Next, we remove our ones digit of x by using floor division which is division that ignores any remainder.

Using the case of x=123, the first iteration sets rev = 3 and x = 12, the second iteration sets rev = 32 and x = 1, the third rev = 321 and x = 0. Which breaks the loop. This is important as it returns the exact reverse of x, which is then compared to x in the last if statement.